# Subtract 5 Days From Concatenated Date

Tags: sql

I have a concatenation in my WHERE clause. It should show YYYYMMDDHHMI so 201710061115. However, now I need to subtract 5 days so then it should be 201710011115. Is this possible? And how would I do this?

```
WHERE cast ((convert(varchar(8),[lOCAL_TIME],112) + replace(convert(varchar(5),[lOCAL_TIME],108),':','')) as bigint)
```

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using? T-SQL, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: That is non-standard SQL.